# How do I filter rows in a dataframe that have whole numbers in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and Pandas and I am struggling a bit with this.

I have a set of data with an `Age` column of type `float64`.  Some of the values have a fractional part and some do not.  I want to remove all the rows that have whole number values for `Age`.

This was my attempt at it:

```
estimatedAges = train[int(train['Age']) < train['Age']]
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 #estimatedAges = train[train['Age'] > 1]
>   ----> 2 estimatedAges = train[int(train['Age']) < train['Age']]
>         3 estimatedAges.info()
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
>        76             return converter(self.iloc[0])
>        77         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
>   ---> 78                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
>        79 
>        80     return wrapper
>
> TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'`>

So, it looks like `int()` does not work on series data and I am going to have to find another approach, I'm just not sure what that other approach is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for cast to `int`:

```
estimatedAges = train[train['Age'].astype(int) < train['Age']]
```

Sample:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[1,2,3.4]})
print (train)
   Age
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.4

print (train[train['Age'].astype(int) < train['Age']])
   Age
2  3.4
```

**Timings**:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[1,2,3.4]})
train = pd.concat([train]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [62]: %timeit (train[train['Age'].astype(int) < train['Age']])
The slowest run took 6.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 544 µs per loop

In [63]: %timeit (train[train['Age'].apply(int) < train['Age']])
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit (train[train.Age > train.Age.round(0)])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop
```

EDIT by comment of [ajcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505895/how-do-i-filter-out-whole-numbers/38505914?noredirect=1#comment64411644_38505914), thank you:

If values are negative and positive float, use:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[1,-2.8,3.9]})
print (train)
   Age
0  1.0
1 -2.8
2  3.9

print (train[train['Age'].astype(int) != train['Age']])
   Age
1 -2.8
2  3.9
```

Comment: I want to check if `.apply(int)` is not faster, but not.

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work for negative values (e.g. it will filter out -3.4). Extra checking is needed - perhaps `!=` instead of `>` would suffice.

Comment: @ajcr - Good to know but fortunately I am not dealing with negative values in my case.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [179]: train[train.Age != train.Age // 1]
Out[179]:
   Age
2  3.4
```

Comment: I thought this worked but then I noticed it was returning fewer rows than @jezrael's solution.  Then I realized any values with a fractional portion greater than 0.5 were being excluded, which makes sense.  If there is a rounding option to always round down then that would work, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately went with @jezreal's answer because his speed tests were convincing but I wanted to add one more solution that I found to the mix.  It requires numpy, but if you have imported pandas then you have more than likely imported numpy as well.

```
import numpy as np
train[np.floor(train['Age']) != train['Age']]
```